# Wrapping beveled curve around a complex shape?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, shrinkwrap

Im trying to make a strap that goes around this object. Right now Im using a curve thats beveled  with a shrinkwrap modifier, but im getting some weird results. [image]

Comment: Hello please share your file so that we can give a try: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but if you take a beziercircle and shrinkwrap it around an object

[image]

you could add a geometry nodes modifier afterwards with this node setup

[image]

and you will get this:

[image]